# MySQL benchmarking: 1 query returning 1000 rows VS 1000 single-row queries

Tags: php, mysql, benchmarking, microbenchmark

Working on an app that requires a very large amount of data transferred from the DB. It includes SELECT and UPDATE queries both (i.e. read and write to the DB).

First I need to get a list of all the products (approx. 1000 SKUs). The SELECT query is very simple:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `my_db`.`products`
```

Then some automatic updates are done to each product. The UPDATE query is something like this:

```
UPDATE
    `my_db`.`products`
SET
    `updated` = NOW(),
    `mods` = `mods` + 1,
    /* a couple more updated fields here, if needed */
```

Now the question is which one would be faster/better to perform: a single query that manipulates with all the records at once, or a PHP loop (e.g. `foreach` or `while`) that works with each product separately (1000 single-row queries)? The latter would require a `WHERE model = 'ABC'` and `LIMIT 1`, of course.

To make the matter more complex (and comprehensive), think of other affecting criteria, e.g.:

- What if a different number of rows was targeted: 100 or 100,000?
- What if more than one table was involved? See an example of a JOINed query below.

.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `my_db`.`table1` AS `t1`
    INNER JOIN `my_db`.`table2` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`fk`
    INNER JOIN `my_db`.`table3` AS `t3` ON `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`fk`
    /* Etc. */
```

**Is there a general "rule of thumb" to decide which way is better in this or that situation?**

Comment: "Here's the SELECT query" - I do not see the query?

Comment: I can't for the life of me see this SELECT query

Comment: so you mean `repeat 1000 times (SELECT; UPDATE;)` vs `SELECT; repeat 1000 times (UPDATE)`? And there is no select query.......

Comment: Let me update the post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good statement which includes 1000 records will always be more efficient than perform 1000 queries, as long as your sql statement is well written.